# VolumeClaimTemplates with subPath

Tags: kubernetes

In a Kubernetes cluster, I need to have a **StatefulSet** bound to a volume (**volume 0** in the picture) and for each replica, it should claim on a subPath folder (replica1 on folder node0, replica 2 on folder node1, ...).

[image]

I could not do such a thing. Any suggestion?

I thought it was possible to instruct the statefulset to use a subPath.
Like this example:

[statefulset.yml]

```
  ...
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: my-claim
    spec:
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
      storageClassName: volume-0
      subPath: node
```

Did someone have such a use case?

Comment: Did you find a way?

Comment: No, as far as I understood there's no way to provide a subfolder inside a volume as I described. Maybe a feature request should be done.
But I don't know if this use case is appreciated. You're the first one who shows some interest.

Comment: I'm curious to understand what's your purpose. Where did you find out that `volumeClaimTemplates` supports `subPath` clause

Comment: I didn't. A customer of my company was asking for such a use case. They wanted to dedicate one volume only to a group of application (statefulset) and each of them should write in a folder of that volume.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `subPath` in the `VolumeMounts` clause.

For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-lamp-site
spec:
    containers:
    - name: apachephp
      image: php:7.0-apache
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/www/html
        name: apachephp-data
        subPath: html
      - mountPath: /var/www/upload
        name: apachephp-data
        subPath: upload
    volumes:
    - name: apachephp-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: apachephp-claim-data
```

The `volumeMounts.subPath` property can be used to specify a sub-path inside the referenced volume instead of its root.
To be clear, I suggest to use `subPath` clause to sharing one volume for multiple Pods, or even for multiple uses inside a single Pods .

Comment: thank you for your reply. Subpath is to me well-known, but the problem is with StatefulSets, where each instance should mount a new folder in a volume

Comment: Since k8s v1.17 `subPathExpr` exists, this could match. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath-with-expanded-environment-variables